# How do I undo accidentally setting Google Docs to autocorrect 'you' to 'your'?

Tags: google-docs

In a grammar mistake on Google Docs, I put 'I used you phone.' I then right-clicked, and said 'always change to your.' Now, whenever I type 'you' in Google Docs, it changes to 'your'. How do I undo this?

If it matters, I use Google Chrome.

Answer (score 5):

Open up a doc in Google Docs, then go to `Tools - Preferences`. It should then be here as an auto replace.

[image: Google Doc Prefs]

Comment: New corrections are added to the bottom of the list.